# Long queries on very short documents

Tags: solr, lucene

I'm fresh out of the nursery as far as Lucene/Solr are concerned, so I may be trying to utilize it completely wrong, but I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

My documents (less than 3,000) are short statements from a taxonomy.  All are single sentences, with some having no more than 4-6 words long.  There is only one field for each document, so searching across multiple fields is not a route I would be looking into.  What I would like to do is query the contents of a work related document and have the taxonomy statements that are relevant returned.

Currently I am using the default example setup that came with Solr with added verb synonyms from Wordnet since performed actions are what I am trying to identify (i.e. taxonomy statement of 'Alter garments to specifications').

Basic word matching works as expected, but I would like to make things somewhat more sophisticated. Since the queries are so long I never end up with a high relevancy scores when searching against the tiny documents. I'm sure this can be resolved by normalizing scores in some fashion so I am not real concerned about the scores coming out, but the actual statements (documents) that are being identified.

Would I be better off indexing the documents (currently the long queries) on the fly and querying each taxonomy statement and compiling/sorting the results or can I perform these long queries on the tiny documents effectively in some other fashion?  I presume this may present it's own difficulties.

Comment: I refered the wikipedia entry on Taxonomy, and I still dont understand your question. Please include a few sample documents and queries and how they are supposed to match. What kind of analysis do you want to perform of them?

Comment: 3000 documents is a very small number anyway. A python script storing it all in memory would take a few MBs of RAM, take no time processing it, and store/retrieve it from disk in a blink. So you can implement any required algorithm yourself. Identifying "performed actions" seems a job for a "part of speech" algorithm (noun, verb etc). Data minng packages like Mahout can do that.

Comment: @aitchnyu - Unfortunately I do not know anything about SA or LSI to be able to write my own algorithms. I was hoping I could utilize something like Solr to get me a jump start here.  I need to know specifically if a certain statement(s) exists within a document.  The wording could be completely different (synonyms, etc), but I need to be able to catch it.  I am sure this stuff can be done with algorithms and POS tagging, but I don't know how to do it.  Additionally I'm not very good with Java at all so that hinders me with some tools.

Comment: @aitchnyu - An example document is given above.  The query could be anything such as a job description, user guide, tutorial......anything at all.

Answer (score 0):

I see no end to what are you trying to do here, i mean your short documents index will definitely suffer from lake of information, and a long query will make every result almost flat in front of it, even expanding the document by adding every term with Wordnet synonyms will be confusing and misleading i think, my advice is to chack other possible forms of the query.